# How to replace a string url

Tags: javascript

I have a string "D:\folder\image.jpg" and I want to change it to "`http://ip/VDrive/folder/image.jpg`".

I tried something like this:

```
var str = "D:\folder\image.jpg";
str = str.replace("D:\\", "http://ip/VDrive/");
result = str.replace("\\", "/");
```

but it doesn't work. I'm edited the external js file directly from VS2008 I hope it has nothing to do with it.

Please help me with this.

Comment: You do realize your string has (lowercase) `d` and you are trying to replace a (capital) `D`?

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, so make sure to use `toLowerCase()` or `.toUpperCase()` as required. What is the output from `result`?

Comment: I tried to change it to capital as well but it's still the same. Let me edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\f` is translated to a special symbol. You need to escape the starting string to:

```
var str = "d:\\folder\\image.jpg";
```

Also, in the replace statement, if you want to make it case sensitive consider regular expressions:

```
str = str.replace(/D:\\/i, "http://ip/VDrive/");
```

But this will produce: `http://ip/VDrive/folder\image.jpg`

So, convert the remaining `\` to forward slashes:

```
str = str.replace(/\\/g, "/");
```

Comment: What is the best way to replace the initial string "d:\folder\image.jpg" to "d:\folder\image.jpg"?

Comment: If that string is generated via a server code, you need to sanitize it for javascript first, that is do a string replacement of "\" with "\\" on the server side. Then process things in javascript as I've shown above.

Comment: Actually the string was came from the <%Eval(FilePath)%> that return the path of the file in this format "d:\folder\image.jpg" for example.

Comment: It came from this:
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="lFilename" ID="grdlinkFilename" Text='<%#Eval("FILEPATH").ToString()%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>'  OnCommand="grdlinkFilename_click" data-id='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>'> </asp:LinkButton>

Then I did this inside the jquery file:

var result = $("#grdlinkFilename").attr("data-id");

I think it will return the same format such as "d:\folder\file.img".

Comment: Then, you can do `<%# Eval("FILEPATH").ToString().Replace("\\", "\\\\") %>`

Comment: Oh I can do that directly inside my linkbutton?

Comment: :) Yep, you don't really need javascript at all for this. You can process everything on the server side.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work for some reason. This is what I did:

<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="lFilename" ID="grdlinkFilename" Text='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>' OnCommand="grdlinkFilename_click" data-id='<%#Eval("FILEPATH").ToString().Replace("\\", "\\\\")%>' </asp:LinkButton>

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "d:\\folder\\image.jpg";     # Escape here
str = str.replace("d:\\", "http://ip/VDrive/");    # Case sensitive
result = str.replace("\\", "/");
```

Answer (score 1):

do

```
var str = "d:\folder\image.jpg";
var newstr = str.replace("d:\folder", "http://ip/VDrive/folder/");
console.log( newstr );
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJrEc/)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var str = "d:\folder\image.jpg";
```

to

```
var str = "d:\\folder\\image.jpg";
```

then it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
// for a dynamic str
var file = str.split("\");
var to = "http://ip/VDrive/" + file[file.length-1]`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "d:\\folder\\image.jpg";
result = str.replace("d:\\", "http://ip/VDrive/").replace(/\\/g, "/");
```